# Execute script in text mode and keep interpreter open

Tags: scripting, command-line

I'm on linux using Mathematica 12.1.1 in text mode, i.e. command line.

How do I execute a script (which for me just means a text file with valid Mathematica expressions in it), display the results and keep the interpreter open?

If I do

```
math < myfile.m
```

mathematica will execute the content of `myfile.m` but at the end will quit. I'd like to be able to perform further computations on the results after executing everything so I'd like to keep the interpreter open. How do I do that?

Usually interpreters have command line switches for this:

for example, in Maple, I'd do

```
maple -F < myfile.mpl
```

or in gnuplot the same thing can be achieved via

```
gnuplot myfile.mpl -
```

So it's a bit odd if this would be completely impossible in mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [the init.m documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html): "To specify another file to be used for kernel initialization in addition to init.m, use the kernel command-line option *-initfile file*, where *file* is the additional initialization file."

So try this in the Linux command line:

```
./math -initfile myfile.m
```